# Difference between put up/ put on

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I was looking for the meaning of "put up" and came across this explanation in a [dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/put-up) : " [***put up something***] to make a particular effort in order to achieve or prevent something :

> For example :The victim was able to ***put up*** little resistance.
>
> Residents have ***put up*** a fight against plans to build a new road.

And the dictionary gives extra information :[***put up or put on*** BRITISH] to show a particular level of skill or ability in doing something, especially in a competition.

> For example: Liverpool ***put up/on*** a marvellous performance
>   throughout the game.

What is the difference here? Can I use "put on" in the first two sentences as well?

I have made some examples to understand the issue:

> Marc Gasol ***put on/up*** a great game last night.(He is a basketball player.)
>
> He ***put on/up*** a great fight in the ring last night. (He is a
>   boxer. We are talking about box match and boxing ring.)
>
> Ricky Gervais ***put on/up*** an enormous show last night. (He is a comedian,
>   making stand-up shows.)

Comment: Put up a defence/resistence/wall/fight, but you put on a performance/show. I'm really not sure about the Marc Gasol one - I'm leaning towards put on, if he had a good overall performance, but if he was particularly good in defense/blocking, then maybe put up. I don't think you would structure that sentence that way anyway. *Marc Gasol **had** a great game last night* sounds much more natural

Comment: Hmm how can I differentiate them? (put up and put on in this specific meaning?) Doesn't a boxer  show a particular level of skill or ability in box match? (It is a competition in some ways)

Comment: I think put up might be slightly more to do with conflict. so a boxer who puts on a show would be entertaining to watch - a crowd pleaser. but a boxer who puts up a show might describe someone valiant in their efforts, but not necessarily in a pretty way. This is why comedians put on shows and armies put up a defence. Put up is more functional (as in putting up a wall) and put on is more to do with presentation (put on a lovely spread of sandwiches). In lack of a proper answer, that's the only way I can think to discern the difference.